# Can I refuse to answer stupid questions at immigration?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, legal, jamaica

Is it legal for customs and immigration officers to ask me the reason I travelled out of the country and return the same day?

Comment: What citizenship?

Comment: @Flimzy what makes you think this is a question about US customs? The tag seems to imply it's Jamaica.

Comment: @drat: I don't think it's about US customs. But I think the answer there answers this question, and that's the litmus test for a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not a citizen, you can refuse to answer stupid questions, provided you don't mind being denied entry, flown home immediately at your own expense, and possibly having a much lower chance of being able to enter in the future. Otherwise, you need to answer the questions; countries are generally under no obligation to admit non-citizens (EU stuff aside). Also, that question is *not* a stupid question; it is unusual for tourists to leave a country and try to reenter the same day, which means any immigration officer is going to wonder if you really are a tourist.